# addOnCompleteListener is completely skipped when getting user from firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following in a login activity that gets triggered to sign in a user to my app:

```
   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                ...
                LoggedInUser loggedInUser = LoggedInUser.getInstance();

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.welcome_back) + loggedInUser.getUser().name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The sign in and the listener above are successfully triggered. However, I am having an issue occur on that Toast line where I call *loggedInUser.getUser().name*

```
    public User getUser() {
    if (user == null) {
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userID);

        databaseReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                }
                else {
                    User currUser = task.getResult().getValue(User.class);
                    user = currUser;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return user;
}
```

What happens here is that *databaseReference.get().addOnCompleteListener* never gets triggered so user is never set, it returns null and the app crashes.

I utilized the same code I have in getUser to set a user elsewhere with no issues so I am not sure what I am missing here that is causing the listener to be skipped. I am new to firebase so any help to understand and fix this is appreciated!

Comment: Hi please refer to these official documents maybe this help
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth
if you want get user data only

Comment: @AmninderSingh I'm not having any issues authenticating or signing the user in

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your code but you can get your user object from `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` inside `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Refer to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start#java_5).

Also bear in mind that calls to the Firebase database are asynchronous. So this means in your `getUser()` method, you'll probably get a null return when you enter the `if == null` block i.e your `addOnCompleteListener` executes after your `return user` statement.

Comment: Thank you, I know I can get the user like this but I would like to store it in a user object when getUser is called. As for your second point, how can I avoid getting null here and having onCompleteListener executing after the return? Is there away around this?

Comment: I'd say that this is more of a UX issue. Here is a recommendation for you to try.
1. Create a method called updateUI or so which takes the user object as a parameter
2. When user is signing in, you show a progress indicator
3. Inside `onComplete` of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method, call `getUser`.
4. Inside `addOnCompleteListener` of `getUser` call updateUI with the user object
5. Inside updateUI, you can hide the progress indicator -> you should have the user object here

You would need logic for null values, task not successful etc. as well and update the UI accordingly.